# Why is my GoLang algorithm going on an infinite loop?

Tags: algorithm, go

I have been trying to solve the problem below in multiple ways (recursively, with the Go-version of do while loop, and with a for loop). But each one of them goes to an infinite loop. I tried using the same solution in JavaScript, and it works perfectly fine. Can someone please help me understand why the solution below is not working/going on an infinite loop?

```
// Write a function that takes in a number and returns the next number that is divisible by 7
package main                   

func solution9(num int) int {  

        var done bool = false  
        var result int = 0     

        for i := 1; done != true; i++ { 
                if (num + i % 7 == 0) {         
                        result = num + i                
                        done = true                     
                }              
        }                      

        return result          
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Your issue is operator precedence. The % operator has a higher precedence than the + operator, so if your `num` is, say, 10, your test is functionally:

```
10 + (0 % 7) == 0 => false (10)
10 + (1 % 7) == 0 => false (11)
10 + (2 % 7) == 0 => false (12)
```

etc.

Obviously, for any `num` > 0, you'll never satisfy the condition. Change your test to `(num+i)%7 == 0` and you should find it works as expected.

Comment: You're an angel. Lol. Thank you Chris!